# OS X Safari keeps forgetting cookies

Tags: macos, safari, cookies

My Safari constantly keeps forgetting cookies, even during a session. I.e. I might log into this Stack Exchange, and a few minutes later I am logged out again (without even restarting Safari). This also affects other sites (e.g. Google).

However, when looking at "Manage Website Data..." in Safari's privacy settings, it looks like the cookies are there (although I'm not 100% sure about this).

Possibly related messages in Console.app:

```
08/11/16 16:29:23,214 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.pid.WebContent.99118) Path not allowed in target domain: type = pid, path = /System/Library/StagedFrameworks/Safari/SafariShared.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/com.apple.Safari.History.xpc/Contents/MacOS/com.apple.Safari.History error = 147: The specified service did not ship in the requestor's bundle, origin = /System/Library/StagedFrameworks/Safari/WebKit.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/com.apple.WebKit.WebContent.xpc
08/11/16 16:29:24,329 Safari[73815]: tcp_connection_tls_session_error_callback_imp 474 __tcp_connection_tls_session_callback_write_block_invoke.434 error 22
08/11/16 16:29:24,357 Safari[73815]: ***cachedResponseDictionaryForRequest:key:handler failed: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.nsurlstorage-cache was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.nsurlstorage-cache was invalidated.}; {
NSDebugDescription = "The connection to service named com.apple.nsurlstorage-cache was invalidated."; }
08/11/16 16:30:42,284 Safari[73815]: KeychainGetICDPStatus: keychain: -25300
08/11/16 16:30:42,284 Safari[73815]: KeychainGetICDPStatus: status: off
```

I have already run "Repair Permissions", to no avail. I have also deleted all cookies and started from scratch, however Safari still forgets newly added cookies.

Also, until a few weeks ago, everything ran just fine. Installed extensions are NoMoreiTunes, Save to Pocket, Ghostery and SaveFrom.net helper.

Any ideas on what could be the culprit or something else I could try?

I am running Safari 10.0.1 on OS X 10.11.6 (although the issue already occurred with Safari 9).

**Edit: Screenshot of Safari's privacy settings, as requested in the comments:
[image]**

Comment: Could you include a screen capture of `Safari > Preferences... > Privacy`?

Comment: @danielAzuelos added to the post.

Answer (score 1):

Something you can attempt:

1. Enter Recovery mode (<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> on startup)
2. Go to Utilities -> Terminal
3. Enter this command `resetpassword` and hit enter.
   At the bottom of the window that appears, you will see "Reset Home Directory Permissions and ACLs". Click "Reset" and reboot.

This will hopefully resolve the permissions issue you're encountering, assuming it is rooted in a permissions issue- perhaps you manually migrated your user folder at some point?

Comment: This might have worked - let me check for another day and then accept the answer in case it still works. Thanks already!

Comment: Seems like the problem has appeared again :-(